# Client validation before sending it to the server in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a model I use for sending login information to the server, for simplicity consider it as

```
public class NewUser
{  
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}
   public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

I've also a controller that accepts the NewUser as Post Parameter and then save it to DB, this part is fine....

On my view I wish to have a client side check to verify the password has been inserted twice matches (you know the re-type password field)

on my Razor view I've

```
@using(Begin.RenderForm(actioncontroller))
{
//maps the fields to the model
then I should have something as
@Html.TextBox("tbPass2")
[...]
<input type="submit" value="insert"/>
}
```

How can I perform this check without having a second Password field and match it on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare two properties of a model there is a [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) validation attribute.

> Model

```
public class NewUser
{  
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}

   [Required]
   public string Password {get;set;}

   [Compare("Password")]
   public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

> View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)

    <input type="submit" value="insert" />
}
```

> Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(NewUser model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // validation successful
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); // or any other logic
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

> Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

To perform a client validation make sure you have the following scripts included in your page: 
`jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. The order of the scripts should remain the same.

Comment: Hello,the code you posted performs a server side validation,to use client side validation after having putted the 3 js what should I do?Thanks

Comment: @advapi, nothing. It also performs a client side validation. Make sure you have it enabled in the web.config file. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in 2 ways

1. Using Form Collections

   ```
   public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection collection_)
   {
   string pass2 = collection_["tbPass2"].ToString();
   }
   ```

2  Receiving the parameters directly

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddNewLink(string tbPass2)
{
}
```

To make the above things work make sure your controll has same name

For above case it should be `@Html.TextBox("tbPass2")`